# System Resource Usage High due to http Hack Attempts

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

I have WordPress website created in a Linux box with Apache as webservice and MySQL serving database.

Recently hackers is trying to hack website using POST methods. Those requests are denied by the server but memory got filled up by these kind of continuous requests and the service like apache, MySQL got stopped.

So my question is how we can prevent such attack request won't use the server resource?. Are there any mod_security rule available for explicitly deny attack without using server resource ?. Please advice.

Below are the log entry for POST attack.

```
134.175.91.239 - - [30/Nov/2018:15:15:34 +0000] "POST /wp-admins.php HTTP/1.1" 403 743 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
134.175.91.239 - - [30/Nov/2018:15:15:36 +0000] "POST /m.php?pbid=open HTTP/1.1" 403 743 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
134.175.91.239 - - [30/Nov/2018:15:15:38 +0000] "POST /db_dataml.php HTTP/1.1" 404 30163 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
134.175.91.239 - - [30/Nov/2018:15:15:43 +0000] "POST /mx.php HTTP/1.1" 404 30168 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
134.175.91.239 - - [30/Nov/2018:15:15:47 +0000] "POST /xshell.php HTTP/1.1" 404 30173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
134.175.91.239 - - [30/Nov/2018:15:15:48 +0000] "POST /qq.php HTTP/1.1" 404 30158 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
134.175.91.239 - - [30/Nov/2018:15:15:58 +0000] "POST /phpstudy.php HTTP/1.1" 404 30163 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
134.175.91.239 - - [30/Nov/2018:15:16:02 +0000] "POST /phpStudy.php HTTP/1.1" 404 30188 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
134.175.91.239 - - [30/Nov/2018:15:16:06 +0000] "POST /weixiao.php HTTP/1.1" 404 30173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
134.175.91.239 - - [30/Nov/2018:15:16:07 +0000] "POST /feixiang.php HTTP/1.1" 404 30173 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
134.175.91.239 - - [30/Nov/2018:15:16:10 +0000] "POST /ak47.php HTTP/1.1" 404 30168 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
134.175.91.239 - - [30/Nov/2018:15:19:26 +0000] "POST /ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application HTTP/1.1" 404 30150 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

Comment: It is not typical to run into resource issues from random 404/403 responses every other second. Can you find syslog entries explaining the unexpected sql server shutdown (try searching for `oom`)?

Comment: I checked the message log and noticed the MySQL service is killed by kernel due to low memory at the  time the attack happening

Comment: Please edit your question and add the size of your VM (CPUs, RAM), parts of your MySQL and httpd configurations relevant to preformance, an example OOM syslog, and statistics on how many unique IP addresses are involved.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared any details about the resource usage of your server, so it's hard to give any recommendation on that.
As you've stated yourself, due to MySQL being OOM-killed, it might need more RAM.

A few tips:

- Consider using `php-fpm` instead of `mod_php`. It reduces apache's memory usage and lets you use apache's event worker model.
- Use `fail2ban` to ban offending IP addresses. Beware of banning legitimate ones if you don't set it up right for your needs though.

Comment: My main concern is how to explicitly deny the hack attempt request. Normally there is no issues with running  services and it only use minimal resource. The resource usage is only high when attack happens.  So how to actively prevent attack with minimal resource usage?

Comment: Then do have a look at fail2ban - this accomplishes what you want.

Comment: Already tried and doesn't helped to prevent attack.

Comment: well, if you did it right the attack doesn't hit the web server. If you still see log entries, the requests were not blocked. So assuming you did it right, something else might be plaguing your server.

Comment: Do you have any recommended blog article which I can follow to prevent such kind wordpress attacks ?